# Populating TableView with Plist Documents Directory in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, plist

- I'm a newbie to `Objective-C` so any help is greatly appreciated.
- I have a `TableView` that is successfully pulling back the list from my `Data.plist` file within my Xcode project but I need it to pull from the **Documents Directory**.
- I have seen many posts about this but can't seem to get it to work for me.
- Here is my .m file below.  Like I said, it pulls back the data but I need it to be dynamically changed based on my Documents plist copy.

Thanks in advance!

```
 @synthesize content = _content;

 - (NSArray *)content
{
    if (!_content) {
        _content = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"]];
    }
    return _content;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.content count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Name"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Score"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This code reads from the resource bundle. Where is your code to read the data from the Documents folder? Do you have code to put the initial file in the Documents folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

**Step 1:** In .h File declare a global variable

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableDictionary *contents;
```

**Step 2:** In .m file set **synthesis**.

```
@synthesize contents;
```

**Step 3:** Move plist file from **mainbudle into documents directory**

```
-(void) createPlistDocuments
{
    // Get path to documents directory
    NSArray *arrayPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    // Finds the contained Documents directory
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [arrayPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSError *error;
    // Create an object that we will later use to look for a file and return a boolean value on whether or not it exists
    NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    // File we want to move, stored in original top level directory
    NSString *demoFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"];
    // Define where we want it moved to and name it
    NSString *demoFileMoved = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/data.plist", documentsDirectory];
    // Attempt the copy
    if ([manager copyItemAtPath:demoFile toPath:demoFileMoved error:&error] != YES)
    NSLog(@"Unable to move file: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

**Step 4:** Read plist data from **document directory**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self createPlistDocuments];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
    NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/data.plist",documentsDirectoryPath];
    contents = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSLog(@"%d", contents.count);

}
```

For brief explanation follow this sample...  [TechDevMobile(IOS-Message-Chat)](https://github.com/Tech-Dev-Mobile/IOS-Message-Chat)

Comment: Rajesh - thanks for the detailed example.  This table is coming back with no contents.  I added the following NSLog: NSLog(@"%@", documentsDirectory);

This gets me the right path to the plist file being created/used.  When I open that, it is poorly formed xml.  See below:

bplist00¢“UScoreTNameR10XJohn Doe“R20YBilly Bob',/ 9

This is how the original plist was formed in my Xcode:

<plist version="1.0">
<array>
<dict>
   <key>Name</key>
   <string>John Doe</string>
   <key>Score</key>
   <string>10</string>
</dict>  

etc...

Comment: Just to follow up, it seems to be writing a file out to the documents directory, just not in the format I would expect and not to where I can successfully read it in my table view.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Still have more doubts.. Just follow this sample to read plist https://github.com/Tech-Dev-Mobile/IOS-Message-Chat

Comment: Now use above code.. I made some changes in that.. First you need to move main bundle file into document directory then only you can get file from document directory. If you are creating plist file by pasting in document directory means just use viewdidload code only..

Comment: Thanks Rajesh!  It looks like I'm all set!